# c# DataContext.SubmitChanges() not updating database

Tags: c#, linq, datacontext

Can someone explain why the following code fails to update the database or what else I can do to troubleshoot?

```
// *********************************
// People Updates
// *********************************
// In Engr and SoE
EmplIDs = InputList.GetPeopleIds(InputType.Engr | InputType.SoE);       // retrieve IDs in tables Engr and SoE
Engr = DB.GetEngrByIds(EmplIDs);                                        // retrieve objects from Engr
SoE = DB.GetSoEByIds(EmplIDs);                                          // retrieve objects from SoE
Batch.Update(SoE, Engr);                                                // update SoE with Engr data
DB.Save(SoE);                                                           // persist


// Inside DB repository
public void Save(List<SoE_People> people) {
    ChangeSet cs = dc.GetChangeSet();
    foreach (SoE_People person in people.Where(p => cs.Updates.Contains(p))) {
        person.LastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
    }

    dc.SubmitChanges();
}
```

I've checked the following:

- people.Count ~ 2500, cs.Updates.Count ~ 200
- dc.GetChangeSet.Updates.Count = 0 after calling SubmitChanges()
- all updates to the people object are correct.  They are visible in the locals window via people and cs.Updates[x]
- no exceptions are thrown by dc.SubmitChanges()
- setting dc.Log = Console.Out shows no SQL for the SubmitChanges()
- a previous section of the code that inserts new records via dc.InsertAllOnSubmit() works fine -> no write permission problem.
- manually cutting and pasting data into the SoE_People table works -> no foreign key constraint problem.

Answer (score 1):

Without even looking into the logic you have above, here are some recommendations:

- Put everything in a try/catch.  How do you know there's no exception being thrown?
- dc.SaveChanges() returns an int - number of records that were CRUDed.  Capture the return value and check it.

Comment: - an uncaught exception should stop the code,
 - the object browser shows that dc.SubmitChanges() returns void
but I will look into this - thanks.

Comment: SubmitChanges() definitely returns a `void` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292162.aspx

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry.. I was thinking of SaveChanges() - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336792.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You have probably overridden SoE_People update in the datacontext.
There should be a this .ExecuteDynamicUpdate(instance).

Look there maybe you have commented / removed that.

You can take a look here if you don't understand what I mean:
[Custom Entity Insert/Update/Delete Method Validation](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/11/linq-to-sql-part-4-updating-our-database.aspx).

Comment: That is a good point.  After the code was deployed, I added some logging which overrode some of the OnPropChanging() events.  That could also explain why I don't see any SQL from dc.Log.

I commented these out after your post but to no avail.  Should I be able to step into these and see if they are trapping my changes?

Comment: I did define interfaces for my tables (i.e.
`public partial class SoE_People : IPerson { }`
but I can't imagine that this would interfere.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with DataContext (don't use it), but I'll throw this out there.

If it's like an SqlDataAdapter, did you write/define the SQL text for inserting or updating your records?

Comment: one of the beauties of DataContext is that you don't have to write the sql :-)

Comment: As soon as my company gets off this old SQL 2000 Server, I **really** need to learn some of this Linq programming!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not the code, it is the database table.
I had the issue to update the table use that SubmitChanges().
I fixed the problem by **giving the table a primary key**.